# How do I make this formula curved?

Tags: curves, interpolation

I'm trying to reverse-engineer the formula that Komatsu uses to indicate how much wear various undercarriage parts have on agricultural equipment.

For each part, they provide at what measurement the part is considered to be 0% worn and a measurement at which the part is considered 100% worn. So for bushings a measurement of 59.3mm is considered 0% worn (unworn, new from factory), and 54.3mm is considered 100%, fully worn (needs to be replaced and the equipment has a high probability of failure, etc.).

The formula I wrote is as follows:

```
result = 100 + (((measurement - fullyWorn) / (fullyWorn - unWorn)) * 100.0)
```

But the official numbers that I'm looking at don't quite match up to that; if I graph the numbers of calculated wear percentage, I see a curve (where the above is a straight line). The closer to the 0% worn value the measurement is, the more the calculated measurement is exaggerated. And the further away from the 0% worn value the measurement is, each mm of measurement has less and less of an effect on the final calculation.

Here, look:

```
Measurement  |    What my formula produces   |  What the official answer is
============================================================================
59.3mm                      0%                                            0%
58.3mm                      20%                             (rounded to) 29% 
57.3mm                      40%                             (rounded to) 49% 
56.3mm                      60%                             (rounded to) 68% 
55.3mm                      80%                             (rounded to) 84% 
54.3mm                      100%                                        100% 
53.3mm                      120%                           (rounded to) 115% 
52.3mm                      140%                           (rounded to) 130% 
51.3mm                      160%                           (rounded to) 144% 
50.3mm                      180%                           (rounded to) 157% 
49.3mm                      200%                           (rounded to) 170% 
48.3mm                      220%                           (rounded to) 183% 
..................
2mm                         1160%                          (rounded to) 653%
1mm                         1180%                          (rounded to) 662%
```

How can I modify my formula so that: A) a small difference between the measurement and the unWorn value produces a large effect, B) a big difference between the measurement and the unWorn value produces a proportionally smaller effect, and C) The measurements at the 0% and 100% values (59.3 and 54.3 in this example) stay as they currently are

Any, ANY direction you could provide would be immensely helpful.

Thank you!!

Comment: How are the official numbers calculated? Where did you find them? I think that's probably where the answer you want is.

Comment: I don't know how the official numbers are calculated; that's what I'm trying to figure out. They're calculated inside of an app to which I don't have access but would like to reproduce. I contacted the manufacturer but haven't heard back yet, and.... probably won't.

Comment: I changed your tags to be more representative. ¶ Just empirically, it looks like you can get from your values to the "official" ones by the map $x \mapsto 2.955 x^{0.765}$ or something like that.  I can't think of any reason why it would look like that, but it works visually.

Comment: It may help a bit if you tell *what* exactly in the bushing is being measured and what sort of bushing it is. Also I'm a bit unsure about what exactly it means for a part to be 662% (or any figure above 100%) worn. Sometimes you can get a fairly idea from the general physics of what is going on, but the information you provided is obviously insufficient for such an attempt.

Comment: What you are looking for is called interpolation, and Brian is suggesting a power law. You can use any reasonable spreadsheet software (e.g. LibreOffice) to find best-fit power law for your data.